# How do i specify to start an application in the specified process?

Tags: batch-file, dos

How to specify to start an application in the specified process in command line.I mean let us take a look at the below command

```
      start "cool.mp3"
```

it opens the file cool.mp3 in the windows media player but i want it to be opened in the VLC player.How do i mention it?How do i tell to open the file in the VLC player or some other real player.Can we mention the application to run in the specified process ? If so how?

Comment: Why don't you start the application you want directly then? Like wmplayer.exe <file to play> for the mediaplayer

Comment: See Joey's answer below. If you know you want to start the vlc player just execute it instead of using the 'start' program.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`start` uses the file associations set by the user. If you want a specific program, then just do so:

```
"%ProgramFiles%\VideoLAN\VLC\vlc.exe" cool.mp3
```

Also note that the example you gave can never work with `start` anyway.